# Why can't I install plugin for android development in netbeans?

Tags: android, netbeans6.7, netbeans-plugins

I'm using netbeans 6.7.1.
I followed the instructions  [from here](http://gerry.ws/2009/01/1074/how-to-setup-netbeans-for-android-development.html)  to install the plugin for android development.
I've riched into the step where I should choose 'Android' in  “Availalble Plugins” tab,and then get into the installation,and get an error list of other plug in's that are not updated enoughf for the android.
Are you familiar with it?
Can I download & install only these I missing,or should I download Netbeans in a more progress version??

Thanks!!
**Izabela**

Answer (score 0):

Open plugin manager. To do this go to Tools | Plugins. Here you need to navigate to Settings tab and add an address of our update center that is

```
http://nbandroid.org/updates/updates.xml if you use NetBeans version 7.3 - 8.0
http://nbandroid.org/release81/updates/updates.xml if you use NetBeans 8.1 (or newer)
```

Previous update center hosted at kenai.com site is removed now as it caused confusion about current version and what is supported and what not.

Obviously your version 6.7.1 is not supported and you have to upgrade your netbeans too.

Comment: website is down where can i get nbandroid?